# vacuumlo command deleted all matched records from postgresql db

Tags: postgresql

My data folder size is 194GB. When I look at the size of PG_LARGEOBJECT table, it is 178GB. So i ran below command to get rid of all unmatched oid's from my database.
vacuumlo -U postgres -W -v DB name

After that I ran the "VACUUM FULL ANALYZE pg_largeobject;" command to free up space.

Issue here is space is freed up but when I look at the application getting Large Object not exists error.

Please help me what I missed.

Comment: From the documentation: vacuumlo works by the following method: First, vacuumlo builds a temporary table which contains all of the OIDs of the large objects in the selected database. It then scans through all columns in the database that are of type `oid` or `lo`, and removes matching entries from the temporary table. (Note: Only types with these names are considered; in particular, domains over them are not considered.) The remaining entries in the temporary table identify orphaned LOs. These are removed. What data type do you use to store the object IDs of the large objects?

Comment: Thanks for the information... I am using oid data type

Comment: You should add more information so this can be reproduced, like SQL statements to create objects and insert data and a `vacuumlo` command that causes the problem.

Comment: I have a Resume table which have 1 column with data type as OID. We are inserting word documents through JAVA application. Application will convert the word document to byte array and stored into the resume table. My model class has this attribute as follows. 
 @Lob
 @Column(name = "orig_document")
 private byte[] document;                                                       
 "vacuumlo -U postgres -W -v DB name"  command I ran to clean up the large objects. then ran the  "VACUUM FULL ANALYZE pg_largeobject;"

Comment: First: add it to the question, not to a comment. Second: do you mean byte array as in `bytea`? Code can resolve ambiguities.

Comment: You are using hibernate? Do you use CLOB  somewhere?